# Xcode issues after installing Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

After updating to Snow Leopard I get an error when trying to install the Xcode.mpkg. The error gives no detailed message to what caused the failure.  When trying to compile previous projects that worked fine in Leopard I now get an error message of "error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.1'".

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

** Update
I found another project that had no issues and in comparison to it there seems to be some odd referencing within the projects with problems. It seems that the path for the referenced sdk got changed somehow. I have set it to point to the new 3.1 and everything is back in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update I found another project that had no issues and in comparison to it there seems to be some odd referencing within the projects with problems. It seems that the path for the referenced sdk got changed somehow. I have set it to point to the new 3.1 and everything is back in order.

** Tim: you were probably right.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you have installed but the xcode package on the snow leopard dvd DOES NOT include the iphone sdk so you have to go [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) and download it after you've upgraded xcode to 3.2

Comment: I have downloaded the latest iphone sdk although installing xcode from the dvd is what was causing the failure to begin with.  It does seem that the iphone sdk upgrade installed xcode 3.2 so maybe the problem isn't as big as I thought.

Any idea on the error that I get when trying to compile. Nothing turns up on google.

Comment: The ability to dev for older versions of the iPhone OS must be installed separately when you install the SDK; did you enable all the appropriate install options? For that matter, does the new SDK even include the ability to dev for 2.1 anymore? I only really remember seeing 2.2-3.1 when I installed it.